# How to reload table in Datatables.js source javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an issue with Datatables where I have a function that builds an array of data to feed into DataTables. However at the end of a row is a cell with a button if that button is pressesed it removes this row from the data that the function just pulled from (sharepoint list).

Now I could just refersh the whole page but that is slow and cluncky.

If I make the button re-run the function I get a `DataTables warning:table id=Ttable2 -Cannnot reinitialise DataTables`

This is my code currently it doesn't tell much, Tbarray is large and not much point i writing it out.

```
$("#tbBody2").empty();
var table = $('#Ttable2').DataTable({
    data: Tbarray,
    scrollY:"475px",
    scrollCollapse: true,

    });
```

**Edit**

```
function BuildSR(Tbarray){

    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#Ttable2')) {
        table.destroy();
    }

    var table = $('#Ttable2').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data: Tbarray,
        scrollY:"475px",
        scrollCollapse: true,
    });

    table.draw();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried? https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: Also, are you doing AJAX to obtain the data or the data is static?

Comment: @acarlstein i'm not using AJAX i'm usual a libaray called SPservices to pull back data from a sharepoint list then putting it into an array the above code in a separate function.

Comment: Did the answer, I had given, solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to destroy and reinitialize the dataTable.

**1. check if dataTable is already initialized, if so - destroy it:**

**edited**

```
//globally initialize var table first
var table;

if (  $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#Ttable2' ) ) {
    table.destroy();
}
```

**2. Then do the initialize with option `destroy: true`**

```
table = $('#Ttable2').DataTable({
destroy: true,
data: Tbarray,
scrollY:"475px",
scrollCollapse: true,
});
table.draw();
```

Comment: i'm getting `Unable to get property 'destroy' of undefined or null reference` when i try to click the button that removes the data and then reloads the function. i added my new code in my edit

Comment: Check your bootstrap version and try with "bDestroy": true, flag instead of destroy

Comment: @adamWadsworth I edited section 1 of my code to globally initialise the variable `table` first... otherwhise u get the `undefined` error. :) ... u should do that in the first line of your js code

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to [`clear()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()) all table entries and re-populate the table with up to date data, using [`rows.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) method:

```
$('#Ttable2').clear().rows.add(Tbarray).draw();
```

That should be much faster than destroying and re-initializing DataTable.